Drizzle ORM onConflict
okay this is where i am at.
if i try onConflictDoNothing the plan is  to insert a new record into the database. If a record with the same userId and provider already exists, and the apiKey of the existing record is not equal to the apiKey of the new record, the insert operation is skipped and no error is thrown.
  .onConflictDoNothing({
    target: [userId, newSettingInfo.provider],
    where: sql`${settingInfo.apiKey} != ${newSettingInfo.apiKey}`,
  })

i get a a 500 error code and it reads
NeonDbError: syntax error at or near "where"
    at execute 

i am pretty certain this is because i cannot use a where clause in the do nothing option.
so i try the onConflictDoUpdate option to insert a new record in teh database.  If a record with the same userId and provider already exists, and the apiKey of the existing record is not equal to the apiKey of the new record, the existing record is updated with the new apiKey. If they are equal, the insert operation is skipped and no error is thrown.
.onConflictDoUpdate({
    target: [settingInfo.userId, settingInfo.provider],
    set: {
      apiKey: newSettingInfo.apiKey,
    },
    where: sql`${settingInfo.apiKey} != ${newSettingInfo.apiKey}`,
  })

and the error i get for this is
NeonDbError: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
    at execute 
}

so i feel like i am close but i am clearly missing something.
avoid duplicate api key entries

You need to create a compound unique relation in your schema:
export const table = pgTable("table", {
    id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
    ...schema
}, (t) => ({
    unq: unique("unique_relation_name").on(t.column1, t.column2)
}));

